# How can I do server-side pagination with ng-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ngtable

My code is

```
$scope.loadQuestions = function() {
  $scope.questionCount = 0;
  $scope.questionTable = new NgTableParams({
    count: []
  }, {
    total: 19387,
    getData: function($defer, params) {
      $scope.filter.sort = params.orderBy();
      $scope.filter.page = params.page();
      return $http.get("/api/questions", {
        params: $scope.filter
      }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.questionCount = response.data.count;
        return response.data.questions;
      });
    }
  });
};
```

If I do this, it's fine. But that's because I hardcoded the `total`, which doesn't make sense obviously. If I do

```
  return $http.get("/api/questions", {
    params: $scope.filter
  }).then(function(response) {
    params.total(response.data.count);
    $scope.questionCount = response.data.count;
    return response.data.questions;
  });
```

then it `ng-table` fires the `http` request twice for some reason. So what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Though it can be understood what you want, your question is confusing to me.

Comment: Which part - I'm happy to clarify?

Comment: Are they not doing that in their [real world example](http://ng-table.com/#/intro/demo-real-world)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In assuming that you are using one of the older versions of `ng-table` script, the first step is to get the data from your api service, and then to intialize the parameters for `ng-table` that you want.

With `$http` service you will get the data only **ONE TIME** if the request is successful, and inside that service initialize your *ngTableParams*. So you will avoid problems with multiple callbacks.

Note also the changes in *getData* part how ordering and filtering are solved with pagination.

Here is the solution that I used for my projects, hope it helps.

```
$http.get('/api/questions').success(function (data) {
                $scope.questionTable = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count: 10
                },
                {
                  total: data.length,
                  getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : data;
                    params.total(orderedData.length);
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: Of course it don't have to be server side pagination, but in this situation I gave generally solution that works correctly. And this is not a reason to vote down my answer...

Comment: The question asks specifically for server side pagination

Answer (score 0):

I am not entierly sure if below would solve your issue, but I do use below code and its not causing double call issue

```
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    if (timeout) $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                    timeout = $timeout(function () {
                        callback().then(function (data) {
                            params.total(data.TotalCount);
                            $defer.resolve(data.PageData);
                        });
                    }, 700);
                }
```

Note: code pasted above is part of a directive, the $timeout part is to avoid multiple calls (throttling) and `callback()` does the actual $http call.

The important part to take for you from here is may be: `$defer.resolve(data.PageData)` is doing the trick for me
also there is no `return` statement like it is there in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create function , inside that function calling the api.

For second call you need to changes `ngtableparam` name means like if earlier was  `tableparam`  now you need to create `tableparam1` or something.

please see the below code

on ng click

```js
    $scope.NextPrev=function(param){
        //code here
        //call another function  
        $scope.tablerefresh($scope.Inedx)
    }
    
     
    $scope.tablerefresh=function(param){
        $scope['tableparater1']={
           reload: function () {},
           settings: function () {return {} }
         }
         $timeout($scope.getdatafromApi(number) ,100); //call those function that gets the data from api
         $scope.tableparater1.reload();
    };
    $scope.getdatafromApi=function(number){
        $.ajax({
           //ajax code here
        }).then (function (response)) {
            data=response;
            $scope.tablaparm.reload(); // reloadfirst call data
        }
       //assigning the data into $scope.tableparater1
       $scope.tableparater1=new ngTableParams({})
    }
```